# METHOD type in ICS file for meeting update in Calendar

Tags: php, vcalendar

I have developed an app on Laravel in which I send meeting invitations via Vcalendar Api.

What METHOD type is to be used in ICS file when I want to update a particular meeting in calendar.

I have used:

`METHOD:CANCEL`
for meeting cancellation with same uid so that it's cancelled.

`METHOD:REQUEST`
For new request

Do we have any method like `METHOD:UPDATE` so that the meeting with same UID is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

The `METHOD:REQUEST` will be used in case of update using the same UID that was used initially.